# How to rewrite a column with new values?

Tags: r

I have column named `count_of_people` in the data SocialData. I want to find the log values of `count_of_people` and replace the values of `count_of_people` with the new log values. How can this be accomplished?

Tried the following: 
`within(SocialData, count_of_people <- log(SocialData$count_of_people))` but it did not work.

Comment: @RStudent worked great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options are available

In general:

```
SocialData$count_of_people <- log(SocialData$count_of_people)
```

but I think that is ugly, and so most useful when programming your own functions.

Alternatives that I find nicer/more readable in scripts are:

```
SocialData <- transform(SocialData, count_of_people = log(count_of_people))
```

or

```
SocialData <- within(SocialData, count_of_people <- log(count_of_people))
```

E.g.

```
set.seed(10)
SocialData <- data.frame(A = 1:10, count_of_people = rpois(10, 5))

SocialData.t <- transform(SocialData, count_of_people = log(count_of_people))
SocialData.w <- within(SocialData, count_of_people <- log(count_of_people))

head(SocialData.t)
head(SocialData.w)
```

Giving:

```
> head(SocialData.t)
  A count_of_people
1 1       1.6094379
2 2       1.3862944
3 3       1.3862944
4 4       1.7917595
5 5       0.6931472
6 6       1.0986123
> head(SocialData.w)
  A count_of_people
1 1       1.6094379
2 2       1.3862944
3 3       1.3862944
4 4       1.7917595
5 5       0.6931472
6 6       1.0986123
```

Your `within()` call looks OK (except for the redundant `SocialData$` in the `log()` call. Did you assign the output from the `within()` call back to the `SocialData` object? If not, you created a new data frame with the modification and then printed or threw it away without changing the original `SocialData` object.